# Express API gives Gateway Time Out error along Cors error while deploying in a Docker Container inside AWS

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I have created Rest Api's with ExpressJs, Node and Typescript. I have another Angular application which tries to consume it. So i implemented Cors like below.

```
import express from 'express';
import MachineSummary from './machine/machine';
import ModuleSummary from './module/module';
import PartsSummary from './part/parts';
import User from './user/user';
import cors from "cors";
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const options:cors.CorsOptions = {
    allowedHeaders: ["Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "X-Access-Token"],    
    methods: "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    origin: '*',    
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

router.use(cors(options));
router.use('/users', User);
router.use('/machine', MachineSummary);
router.use('/module', ModuleSummary);
router.use('/parts', PartsSummary);

router.options("*", cors(options));

export default router;
```

It's working fine, in my local. But when I move the API's into Docker container, First time when the request goes API sends back the response. After that it sends back Bad Gateway (505 error) along with Cors error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is 505 error is coming for pre flight OPTIONS request. First figure out why 505 is coming. Configure your gateway properly.